# Creating and updating products in BigCommerce via the API results in reformatted proudct codes and SKUs

Tags: bigcommerce

Is there anything in the BigCommerce API that would detect a product code or SKU that resembles a date format (i.e. "12-34-7377") and automatically convert to another date format (i.e. "7377 -12-34").?  We are seeing product codes like this get automatically reformatted by the BC API when creating and updating products via the API.  I have already confirmed that JSON data being sent is the correct data/product code.

Comment: There shouldn't be. Have you verified if anything else is hitting that store's API?

Comment: Nothing else is hitting the BC API to update products.